# How to get TeamCity 10 to return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: angularjs, cors, teamcity

We are using TeamCity 10.0.2 to build/test/etc our current projects. We are currently trying to use TeamCity's built in REST API to access information about builds. To run these REST calls, we are using Angular 1.5's http library to perform the GET requests.

However, when running the GET request, we are receiving the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

What I found online was to add

```
rest.cors.optionsRequest.allowUnauthorized=true
rest.cors.origins=*
```

to our Internal Properties in TeamCity. We did this but are still receiving the error. Note that if we hit the same URL just using a browser or using Postman, it works; the problem occurs when running the request from Angular using

```
$http.get(teamCityUrl, {headers:{"Authorization": "token"}});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: when you make that HTTP call, do you see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? The reason it works in postman is that the CORS header it's required by the browser for security reasons, whilst the restriction is not imposed on Postman

Comment: Also some browser will reject * in that header, so try and only set the domain on which you are hosting your Angular app

Comment: No, I do not see the header on the response. That being said, when I do the request just using the browser (not angular) it works but I still do not see the response. In terms of setting the domain, TeamCity is the server and I do not have control over its API and what it responds.

Comment: ok then you need to check the configuration of teamcity. You may want to read up on CORS, you can hit it directly from the browser because it isn't an AJAX call. The CORS policies are applied to AJAX requests, basically it checks the domain of where the page is loaded from against the domain of where you are trying to reach.

Comment: take a read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: try and change your teamcity settings to the following
`rest.cors.optionsRequest.allowUnauthorized=true
rest.cors.origins=your-domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me with this configuration:

> rest.cors.optionsRequest.allowUnauthorized=true
>   rest.cors.origins=*

That makes the response header to have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'.
I'm using TeamCity 10.0.4.